# Spark Scala case when with multiple conditions

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, case

I'm trying to do a case on a DF I have but I'm getting an error. I want to implement this with built in spark functions - withcolumn, when, otherwise:

```
CASE WHEN vehicle="BMW" 
AND MODEL IN ("2020","2019","2018","2017") 
AND value> 100000 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS NEW_COLUMN
```

Currently I have this

```
DF.withColumn(NEW_COLUMN, when(col(vehicle) === "BMW" 
and col(model) isin(listOfYears:_*) 
and col(value) > 100000, 1).otherwise(0))
```

But I'm getting an error due to data type mismatch, (boolean and string)... I understand my condition returns booleans and strings, which is causing the error. What's the correct syntax for executing a case like that one? also, I was using && instead of **and** but the third && was giving me a "cannot resolve symbol &&"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: so `NEW_COLUMN`, `vehicle`, `model` etc are variables of type `String`? If so, this code runs fine. Do you have `implicits` imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think && is correct - with the built-in spark functions, all of the expressions are of type [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column), checking the API it looks like `&&` is correct and should work fine. Could it be as simple as an order-of-operations issue, where you need parentheses around each of the boolean conditions? The function / "operator" `isin` would have a lower [precedence](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/operators.html) than `&&`, which might trip things up.

Comment: It was due to parentheses haha, I had no idea. Thanks! it's working now and with the && instead of the explicit and.